The image is stretching vertically to the height of the adjacent text box
I am using tailwind css. I have a flexbox container div. The image in this div is stretching vertically along with the adjacent text box. I think it is taking the height of the parent div. This problem is occuring only for specific range of sizes.
I want the image to maintain its aspect ratio so that it does not stretch vertically.
This is what i want it to look like
but for some size range, it is looking like this
This is how the image is stretching
Here is my code-
<main class="flex justify-center pt-36"> <!--main content--> <div class="my-16"> <div class="flex justify-center text-2xl md:text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 mb-2">Heading</div> <div class="md:flex justify-center my-16 mx-16"> <div class="flex justify-center md:flex-none my-16 mx-8"> <img class="min-w-80 md:w-80" src="images/random.jpg" alt="random-image"> </div> <div class="flex justify-center my-16 text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas, ducimus optio perferendis alias vitae saepe officiis deserunt, delectus unde cum doloribus, itaque neque deleniti eligendi quo nobis. At, consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit voluptas placeat eveniet quidem quam assumenda dolorum perspiciatis aliquid temporibus ea, exercitationem, non ullam, eligendi expedita omnis repudiandae delectus! Iste, laboriosam? </div> </div> </div> </main>

In the desired result, the image seems to be smaller in width than your attempt, so let's consider making it narrower. For example, we could have it occupy two-thirds of the width by removing the width-related classes on the <img> element itself, and apply width: 33.33% to its parent <div> element via the w-1/3 class:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<main class="flex justify-center pt-36">
  <!--main content-->
  <div class="my-16">
    <div class="flex justify-center text-2xl md:text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 mb-2">Heading</div>
    <div class="md:flex justify-center my-16 mx-16">
      <div class="flex justify-center md:flex-none my-16 mx-8 w-1/3"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/1080/640" alt="random-image"> </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center my-16 text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas, ducimus optio perferendis alias vitae saepe officiis deserunt, delectus unde cum doloribus, itaque neque deleniti eligendi quo nobis. At, consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit voluptas placeat eveniet quidem quam assumenda dolorum perspiciatis aliquid temporibus ea, exercitationem, non ullam, eligendi expedita omnis repudiandae delectus! Iste, laboriosam? </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>



With regards to the stretching, this happens because the default value of align-items is stretch. This causes the <img> element's parent <div> element to stretch to the height of sibling elements in the same horizontal flex layout. The align-items: stretch then also stretches the <img> element since the parent <div> is also a horizontal flex layout.
So with regards to stopping the stretching, there are many different approaches available, such as:
Applying align-items: start to the flex layout parent:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<main class="flex justify-center pt-36">
  <!--main content-->
  <div class="my-16">
    <div class="flex justify-center text-2xl md:text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 mb-2">Heading</div>
    <div class="md:flex justify-center my-16 mx-16 items-start">
      <div class="flex justify-center md:flex-none my-16 mx-8 w-1/3"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/1080/640" alt="random-image"> </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center my-16 text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas, ducimus optio perferendis alias vitae saepe officiis deserunt, delectus unde cum doloribus, itaque neque deleniti eligendi quo nobis. At, consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit voluptas placeat eveniet quidem quam assumenda dolorum perspiciatis aliquid temporibus ea, exercitationem, non ullam, eligendi expedita omnis repudiandae delectus! Iste, laboriosam? </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>



Applying align-self: start to the <div> parent:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<main class="flex justify-center pt-36">
  <!--main content-->
  <div class="my-16">
    <div class="flex justify-center text-2xl md:text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 mb-2">Heading</div>
    <div class="md:flex justify-center my-16 mx-16">
      <div class="flex justify-center md:flex-none my-16 mx-8 w-1/3 self-start"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/1080/640" alt="random-image"> </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center my-16 text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas, ducimus optio perferendis alias vitae saepe officiis deserunt, delectus unde cum doloribus, itaque neque deleniti eligendi quo nobis. At, consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit voluptas placeat eveniet quidem quam assumenda dolorum perspiciatis aliquid temporibus ea, exercitationem, non ullam, eligendi expedita omnis repudiandae delectus! Iste, laboriosam? </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>



Applying align-items: start to the <div> parent:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<main class="flex justify-center pt-36">
  <!--main content-->
  <div class="my-16">
    <div class="flex justify-center text-2xl md:text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 mb-2">Heading</div>
    <div class="md:flex justify-center my-16 mx-16">
      <div class="flex justify-center md:flex-none my-16 mx-8 w-1/3 items-start"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/1080/640" alt="random-image"> </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center my-16 text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas, ducimus optio perferendis alias vitae saepe officiis deserunt, delectus unde cum doloribus, itaque neque deleniti eligendi quo nobis. At, consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit voluptas placeat eveniet quidem quam assumenda dolorum perspiciatis aliquid temporibus ea, exercitationem, non ullam, eligendi expedita omnis repudiandae delectus! Iste, laboriosam? </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>



Applying align-self: start to the <img>:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<main class="flex justify-center pt-36">
  <!--main content-->
  <div class="my-16">
    <div class="flex justify-center text-2xl md:text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 mb-2">Heading</div>
    <div class="md:flex justify-center my-16 mx-16">
      <div class="flex justify-center md:flex-none my-16 mx-8 w-1/3"> <img class="self-start" src="https://picsum.photos/1080/640" alt="random-image"> </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center my-16 text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas, ducimus optio perferendis alias vitae saepe officiis deserunt, delectus unde cum doloribus, itaque neque deleniti eligendi quo nobis. At, consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit voluptas placeat eveniet quidem quam assumenda dolorum perspiciatis aliquid temporibus ea, exercitationem, non ullam, eligendi expedita omnis repudiandae delectus! Iste, laboriosam? </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>



Removing the horizontal flex layout from the <div> parent:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<main class="flex justify-center pt-36">
  <!--main content-->
  <div class="my-16">
    <div class="flex justify-center text-2xl md:text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 mb-2">Heading</div>
    <div class="md:flex justify-center my-16 mx-16">
      <div class="my-16 mx-8 w-1/3 shrink-0"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/1080/640" alt="random-image"> </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center my-16 text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quas, ducimus optio perferendis alias vitae saepe officiis deserunt, delectus unde cum doloribus, itaque neque deleniti eligendi quo nobis. At, consequatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit voluptas placeat eveniet quidem quam assumenda dolorum perspiciatis aliquid temporibus ea, exercitationem, non ullam, eligendi expedita omnis repudiandae delectus! Iste, laboriosam? </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>



